# Unable to expose my Interface manual class in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed a WCF service, below is a sample TestCode to get the clear understand of the issue:

**IService.cs:**

```
[OperationContract]
List<TestClass> Display(string companyCode, string employeeId);
```

Inside this interface, I have defined **TestClass**:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public System.Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirthOn { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs:**

```
 public List<TestClass> Display(string companyCode, string employeeId)
 {
     try
     {
         TestClass oTestClass = null;
         oTestClass = new TestClass(companyCode);
         List<TestClass> oITestClass =  oTestClass.GetDetails("ABC", someid) as List<TestClass>
         if (oITestClass != null && oITestClass .Count > 0)
         {
             return oITestClass ;
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
             //logger.Debug("No Record Found");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return null;
     }
     finally
     {
         // Nothing To Do
     }
 }
```

The problem is I get the List `null` on the following line

```
List<TestClass> oITestClass =  oTestClass.GetDetails("ABC", someid)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
GetDetails method returning the Interface of TestClass so I have to cast in TestClass

Comment: You need to show us what the `GetDetails` method looks like...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you're not assigning the `oTestClass` variable:

```
TestClass oTestClass = null; // <- This _is_ null
List<TestClass> oITestClass =  oTestClass.GetDetails("ABC", someid)
```

How do you expect it to be anything other than `null`?

This is basic, basic, *basic* knowledge about the language. If you don't know these things, I'd suggest you stay away from WCF and do something more basic until you've learned the language.

You can start by reading about the [`NullReferenceException`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullreferenceexception) :)

Comment: Without knowing how the GetDetails method is implemented. It is difficult to tell you how to fix it. As @khellang points out your code cannot work as there is a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

change the return type of GetDetails to IEnumerable<> instead of List<>, it should work.

```
 TestClass tc = new TestClass();
 IEnumerable<ITestClass> bList = tc.GetDetails();
 IEnumerable<TestClass> dlist = bList as IEnumerable<TestClass>;
```

pls refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

btw, which version of .net you are using?